# What is the use of marking a question as favourite?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I understand the purpose of up-voting or down-voting a question or answer. But there is another option for the questions i.e., *marking a question as favourite*. I don't really understand what purpose it serves. As far as I have searched, I could not find any explanation as to what it is used for. I know that this question does not belong to Electronics SE alone but to the entire SE network. But can anyone here enlighten me about the use of *marking a question as favourite*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike voting, which is for the system and everyone else, marking posts as favorites is for you.  Go to your user profile, and you will see there is a "favorites" tab.  Stuff you mark as favorite shows up in this list.  This is basically a way for you to make your own private list of posts kept for you by the system.

There is one side effect seen by others that I can think of.  The number of users that have marked a question as favorite is shown by that question.  Possibly there is a rep threshold to be able to see the number of uses that marked a question as favorite; I don't remember.

Comment: Agreed, it is to allow you to track it, users get badges from it, but nothing else.